# Physical location of DTO in a project

Tags: wcf, dto, n-tier-architecture

I have a WCF service layer in my application that passes DTOs to UI.

Where is the best place to place my DTO classes in the project, should they have different folder called DTO or is it OK to place then in the folder in which the service using them is located?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put them in a separate assembly (notice - not just  a folder, a dedicated assembly) which both the UI layer and the Service layer can access. I usually call this layer `Entities`, and it BTW usually contains other things also.

Comment: But I am exposing everything via WCF Proxy so the types are getting to my clients via it, why use additional dll ?

Comment: Anyway both your assemblies (WCF+UI) should "know" your DTO classes. How else can that be? You certainly don't want to have 2 copies of your classes. It must be in a common place, and a 3rd assembly which both reference is the solution.

Comment: clients know my DTOs via WSDL

Answer (score 0):

Put your Service DTOs in a seperate Service.Dto project that should live at the SIL. Also, your phrasing probably confused people when you said "passes DTOs to UI". You probably meant passes DTOs to service clients.